# How do I add a Milestone History widget to cases?

Tags: casemilestone

I've seen this before previously in Salesforce, but I don't know how to add it myself. It's a sort of lateral bar which has the history of the milestones - when they fired, etc.

Anyone ever seen anything of the sort?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you'll enable Entitlement in the org you will be able to add to the case layout field called: Timeline(Minutes)